# Navigation Controller View Handling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, xcode4, navigationcontroller

I have a navigation view controller that will show the table view of my application, but I can't get it to move to a new view when I tap an entry in the table.  How do I link a new view to an element in the parent view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `navigation view controller`?

You either have a navigation controller or a view controller.

A navigation controller has a stack of view controllers and pushes and pops between them.

In regards to your question you need to define the tableview's delegate as `self`. If you're subclassing `UITableViewController` then you don't have to worry about this.

Then implement this method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // here is where you can "push" a new view controller
    MyNextViewController *nextVC = [[MyNextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNextViewController" bundle:nil];
    [nextVC setTitle:@"Next View Controller"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextVC animated:YES]; // this is where the next page is "pushed"
    // remember to release
    [nextVC release];

}
```

So in the code above we're using the delegate method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` which gets called when the user "clicks" a table view cell.

You can use the `indexPath` object to find out which row was tapped. `int rowIndex = [indexPath row];` will get you the row index of the cell that was tapped.